# Excel Filter Function Include Different Array for Filtering

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula

I wanted to make a filter function, but the array for criteria is referring to a different cell

[image]

Here is an example

My array is C3:C17, I wanted to filter the names on this array based on the list from A3:A5
Here I tried using this formula

```
=FILTER(HSTACK($C$3:$D$17),C3:C17=A3:A17)
```

I am expecting to return Agent 1, 5 and 10 with their corresponding Leaders on cell F3 but instead the formula only return 1 result which is Agent 1 and Leader 1

Expecting/Desired result

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using `ISNUMBER` and `XMATCH`:

```
=FILTER(C3:D17,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(C3:C17,A3:A5)))
```

[image]

Comment: This is working! But my official roster changes anytime. There might be an additional, or reduction of Agents for instance, how would I make this formula dynamic for that scenario?

Comment: Use a table (Ctrl+T) and refer to the entire table column.

Comment: Tried it, but when I delete one name from my official roster, my filter would show several zeros (these are blanks). Reason for that is I do have additional filter on top of that. Is there a way we can make the xmatch dynamic? Or is there any other function we can use to accommodate changes like these?

Comment: Add an `ISBLANK` check to the filter criteria maybe. Feel free to edit your question with  more detail.

Comment: thanks so much! I figured out on how to use the table you were telling. I should delete the entire row on that table so it won't make a blank space. It is no longer return zeros

Comment: @Harvey you can use TOCOL to make it dynamic: `=FILTER(C:D,(C:C<>"")*(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(C:C,TOCOL(A:A,1)))))` but table references are better.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative: **[BigBen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9245853/bigben)** Sir was pretty quick otherwise I would have opted for `ISNUMBER()` with `XMATCH()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `F3`

```
=FILTER(C3:D17,MMULT(N(C3:C17=TOROW(A3:A5)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(A3:A5))))
```

---

To avoid additional changes in the roster, this will work using `TOROW()` & `DROP()` function: -> The first one is used to exclude the blanks while the latter is used to exclude the top `2` rows.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `F3`

```
=LET(α,TOROW(DROP(A:A,2),1),
FILTER(C3:D17,MMULT(N(α=C3:C17),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(α)))))
```

---

Answer (score 2):

### Filter Using `INDEX/XMATCH`

- Note that this simplification only works if you want to return as many results as there are values in the 'lookup' column (`A`) i.e. if there are no duplicates in column `C`. Otherwise, you need to use `FILTER` and switch the `XMATCH` parameters i.e. do something like BigBen did in his answer.
- Note that you don't need the variables `l`, `s`, `dr`, and `dc` i.e. you can write all of it in one long line. They are used just to better understand what's going on i.e. to make it more readable.

```
=LET(lrg,A3:A17,srg,C3:D17,sc,1,
    l,TOCOL(lrg,3),s,INDEX(srg,,sc),
    dr,XMATCH(l,s),dc,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(srg)),
IFERROR(INDEX(srg,dr,dc),""))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative:

[image]

Formula in `F3`:

```
=FILTER(C3:D17,COUNTIF(A3:A5,C3:C17))
```

Or simply (but slow):

```
=FILTER(C:D,COUNTIF(A3:A5,C:C))
```