# Compare two columns and return related values from third column

Tags: excel, comparison, multiple-columns

I need to compare the SKU column to the New List column and return the associated value in the Assortment column. Is this possible using excel functions?

Here is the example set - Dummy Dataset

[image]

I tried the formula that is provided on this [linked page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76384781/excel-filter-function-include-different-array-for-filtering) and got this back. This is the closest to what I am wanting.

First Attempt

[image]

I got the other suggested formulas to work but they were returning all values in column A that had any of the values in column C where I just want it to return Banana in this case (The example is not the best and I apologize for that).

Other attempt

[image]

I was able to wrap the original formula in a filter, unique, and substitute function to just get banana which is what I want.

Successful Attempt

[image]

The issue now is I can't get this function to work with my actual data. The biggest differences are that all three columns are numbers in my source data and the volume. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:  Adding a new dataset for clarification
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvoEA.png)

I want to return all Assortment Numbers that only have the the ten numbers in column c.

Comment: Are you just wanting to look up the 'New List' number and return the Assortment?  If so, an XLOOKUP may be all you need.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure how to go about using it.  I need it to be a dynamic array to potentially return multiple values.  I used xmatch to return the "other attempt" photo included in the original post.

Comment: To solve your problem, I think we need a clearer picture of what you are trying to accomplish.  Given that every SKU could have multiple Assortments, I'm really not sure what the end goal is.

Comment: I tried adding another dummy dataset.  Does that help?  Sorry!  This question seems doable, but it's hard to articulate.